# Prioritizing I/O for a specific query request in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, io, resource-governor

Sorry for the long introduction but before I can ask my question, I think giving the background would help understanding our problem much better.

We are using sql server 2008 for our web services as the backend and from time to time it takes too much time for responding back for the requests that supposed to run really fast, like taking more than 20 seconds for a select request that queries a table that has only 22 rows. We went through many potential areas that could cause the issue from indexes to stored procedures, triggers etc, and tried to optimize whatever we can like removing indexes that are not read but write frequently or adding NOLOCK for our select queries to reduce the locking of the tables (we are OK with dirty reads).

We also had our DBA's reviewed the server and benchmarked the components to see any bottlenecks in CPU, memory or disk subsystem, and found out that hardware-wise we are OK as well. And since the pikes are occurring occasionally, it is really hard to reproduce the error on production or development because most of the time when we rerun the same query it yields response times that we are expecting, which are short, not the one that has been experienced earlier.

Having said that, I almost have been suspicious about I/O although it is not seem to be a bottleneck. But I think I was just be able to reproduce the error after running an index fragmentation report for a specific table on the server, which immediately caused pikes in requests not only run against that table but also in other requests that query other tables. And since the DB, and the server, is shared with other applications we use and also from time to time queries can be run on the server and database that take long time is a common scenario for us, my suspicion regarding occasional I/O bottleneck is, I believe, becoming a fact.

Therefore I want to find out a way that would prioritize requests that are coming from web services which will be processed even if there are other resource sensitive queries being run. I have been looking for some kind of prioritization I described above since very beginning of the resolution process and found out that SQL Server 2008 has a feature called 'Resource Governor' that allows prioritization of the requests.

However, since I am not an expert on Resource Governor nor a DBA, I would like to ask other people's experience who may have used or is using Resource Governor, as well as whether I can prioritize I/O for a specific login or a specific stored procedure (For example, if one I/O intensive process is being run at the time we receive a web service request, can SQL server stops, or slows down, I/O activity for that process and give a priority to the request we just received?).

Thank you for anyone that spends time on reading or helping out in advance.

Some Hardware Details:
CPU: 2x Quad Core AMD Opteron 8354
Memory: 64GB
Disk Subsystem: Compaq EVA8100 series (I am not sure but it should be RAID 0+1 accross 8 HP HSV210 SCSI drives)

PS:And I can almost 100 percent sure that application servers are not causing the error and there is no bottleneck we can identify there.

Update 1:

I'll try to answer as much as I can for the following questions that gbn asked below. Please let me know if you are looking something else.

1) What kind of index and statistics maintenance do you have please?
We have a weekly running job that defrags indexes every Friday. In addition to that, Auto Create Statistics and Auto Update Statistics are enabled. And the spikes are occurring in other times than the fragmentation job as well.

2) What kind of write data volumes do you have?
Hard to answer.In addition to our web services, there is a front end application that accesses the same database and periodically resource intensive queries needs to be run to my knowledge, however, I don't know how to get, let's say weekly or daily, write amount to DB.

3) Have you profiled Recompilation and statistics update events?
Sorry for not be able to figure out this one. I didn't understand what you are asking about by this question. Can you provide more information for this question, if possible?

Answer (score 1):

first thought is that [statistics](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rob/archive/2008/05/16/sql-server-statistics.aspx) are being updated because of the data change threshold is reached causing execution plans to be rebuilt.

- What kind of index and statistics maintenance do you have please? Note: index maintenance updates index stats, not column stats: you may need separate stats updates.
- What kind of write data volumes do you have?
- Have you profiled Recompilation and statistics update events?

Comment: Yep, statistics being updated was my first thought too but then when considering a table of 22 records is it still likely? We would need to know more about the volatility of data in the table I think. Recompilitation is certainly a possibility. The poster should be able to measure compilation time for the poorly performing query.

Comment: @John Sansom: The 22 row thing could be blocking though. Perhaps it's misleading too with a server "stall"

Comment: I need to find out answers for the questions you asked guys, since I am not that much familiar with this stuff. Will try to turn back ASAP but it may take some time before I got replies from our DBA team. Thanks you interest in the meantime.

Comment: @gbn: Indeed. @Ferhat: Keep us all posted on developments with this.

Comment: @John: I already submitted an update in original post for answering questions that gbn asked earlier, thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0):

In response to question 3) of your Update to the original question, take a look at the following reference on SQL Server Pedia. It provides an explanation of what query recompiles are and also goes on to explain how you can monitor for these events. What I believe gbn is asking (feel free to correct me sir :-) ) is are you seeing recompile events prior to the slow execution of the troublesome query. You can look for this occurring by using the SQL Server Profiler.

[Reasons for Recompiling a Query Execution Plan](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Query_Processing_-_Recompiling_Execution_Plan)

Comment: Hi John,  thanks for the info & link. Once I check it, and hopefully figure out:), I will try to turn back with any additional information I could find out.